# Twilio isn't producing reply SMS messages from generated TwiML

Tags: xml, sms, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to get basic SMS responses working on my server. I have a route set up at http://feedingforward-staging.herokuapp.com/api/sms that correctly produces the following TwiML when you make a GET request in the browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Sms>Hey Monkey. Thanks for the message!</Sms></Response>
```

I've configured my Twilio number to point to this URL, and when I send a text to that number, the server does get the request and processes it with code 200 (OK). However, Twilio does not use the TwiML to send a response text.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with the help of one of the awesome customer service reps at Twilio.

My application was returning headers to Twilio with the content-type set to 'application/json'. I changed it to 'application/xml' and it worked!

Comment: How did you determine the error? Did you use the Logs -> Notifications?

Comment: No, the customer service rep made some calls to my API and examined the headers that came back.

Comment: so no code was changed, then?  Was the configuration changed?  Odd solution.

Answer (score 3):

On your Twilio Dashboard, visit Logs -> Notifcations here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/notifications  and see if there's any sort of message generated when you send a message.

*Disclosure: Twilio employee here.*

Comment: Hi CaseySoftware, can you please have a look at my question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370533/twiml-app-invoke-aws-lambda-when-user-replies-stop-start-for-twilio-number